# Azure Migrate keep test migrations delete recovery services vault

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-backup-vault, azure-migrate

The issue is we migrated from physical servers to Azure using Azure migrate and we started using these test VM's that we got from test migrations but never fully migrated them.

We did the test migration in a different new Subscription and resource group. We would like to keep and continue using these test migration VM's as is. But we are trying to get rid of the old Recovery Services Vault that has unnecessary Azure Site Recovery costs associated with it in the old subscription.

If we were to Cancel and delete the resources within this older subscription that has replicated items. Would the deletion of the Recovery Services vault from the old subscription have any affect on the test migration VM's that currently reside in the other new subscription and resource group?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is always advised to do verification by testing out your specific scenario on a different setup.

From what you wrote I understand that there is a new recovery service vault in place in the new subscription, so it should be safe to delete the resources in the old subscription (still, the above is good advice).

Take note that you can't delete a recovery service vault resource straight away. First, the backups are only "soft deleted". This is so that you can undo the deletion if it caused you any harm.

See this for a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-delete-vault